# Use travis CI to automatically trigger AWS lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, travis-ci

How can I make Travis CI automatically trigger an AWS lambda function after all tests have passed and travis CI builds successfully? Please note the github repo is public.

#### Background

The bigger problem I'm solving is that I have travis CI on a repo. Each time I push, after everything passes, I manually run a lambda which sets off processes in AWS. I will be open sourcing the repo so anyone can contribute, so I want to avoid having to run the lambda manually, but instead have it automatically triggered whenever a pull request is merged successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You could update your travis-ci build to invoke the lambda with the aws-cli, as long as you install it in your travis build. Here is an example:

```
aws lambda invoke --function-name awesome-function --payload '{"some":"data", "targetState": true}' /dev/stdout
```

breakdown:

1. `aws lambda invoke`  is the basic aws-cli command we want to run
2. `--function-name` specifies which function to run
3. `--payload` specifies the event data to invoke the function with
4. `/dev/stdout` specifies that we want the output of the invocation to enter our terminal output

here's the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/invoke.html

Answer (score 0):

- Just putting down my idea here, just wanted to check If this is possible or not. If your container has internet access.
- Why not use a curl command to do a post with appropriate payload on
  to the API Gateway endpoint.
- The lambda can be backed behind the API Gateway.
- IF its going to be a public repo, in that case we don't want to store any credentials on any docker/container.
- Create an IAM user for the container with policies to interact with AWS Lambda invoke only and then use the option of aws cli.

```
- curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"xyz":"testing","abc":"random stuff"}' https://tst.nhsd.io/restapi/Xyzxyz/testing/
```